# Save query result from GET method for future reference

Tags: http, post, get

I want to implement a query on my web page that gets results from another web service and displays them to the user. For this I ofcourse send the request as GET method from the web page. Server side, I process the request, get results from that web service and return them back to user.

However, I also want to save the results for future refernce. Something like history of queries. For this I will store the results in a database.

Now, the question is since I am upating my database everytime a query is made, should I be using POST method on the web page or GET would do? Does HTTP explicitly say anything for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP itself doesn't say you have to use POST -- the technology will work just fine if you're sending your data on queryparams.

But current convention says that you should use POST, specifically when using API services under a RESTful model. If you are passing data (even on the query params) that is creating a new record, it should use the POST verb. Updating it should use PUT.

It's going to get down to what your audience expects. If it's just an internal resource, go for it with GET.  If you expect to open this up as a public service, use POST.